# Failed to load pdf document after downloading the document from IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, jsreport

I have an ajax call where I am calling JSReport and downloading the pdf document. In chrome and other browsers, it works correctly. The document is downloaded and I can open it. But in IE11, the document is downloaded but if I want to open the pdf file, it always shows failed to load pdf document. I debugged the code in IE11 console, but it did not give any error.
Here is my code,

```js
$.ajax({
                url: 'my api url',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedIds),
                success: function (data) {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                    
                    if (!isIE) {
                        // This part is working properly
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + data[i];
                            a.target = '_blank';
                            a.download = 'report.pdf';
                            a.click();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // This part is for IE11 browser where I have problem to load the document after download
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var file = new Blob([data[i]], {
                                type: 'application/octet-stream'
                            });
                            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, 'report.pdf');
                        }
                    }
                    
                },
                fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I try to test your sample code with dummy values. I am getting a network error while downloading the file in Chrome and I got InvalidStateError in IE. If possible can you try to share the dummy values for the parameters that you had used in your code? It can help us accurately reproducing the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you @Deepak-MSFT for your comment. My dummy value which I am getting from the API call is in base64 string format. Due to its length, I cannot post it here. IS there any other information do you want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution! I actually needed to convert base64 string data to Blob. Then we can download it. Previously, it was not converted correctly. This was why the file was downloaded but failed to load since it was damaged. Here is my code is given below,

```js
$.ajax({
                url: 'my api url',
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedIds),
                success: function (data) {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
                    
                    if (!isIE) {
                        // This part is working properly
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + data[i];
                            a.target = '_blank';
                            a.download = 'report.pdf';
                            a.click();
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var base64Data = data[i];
                            var fileName = 'report.pdf';
                            var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);

                            var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

                            for (var j = 0; j < byteCharacters.length; j++) {
                                byteNumbers[j] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(j);
                            }

                            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                },
                fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                }
            });
```